# Hibernate - toString() of a Temporal Column returns different results

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

With an entity:

```
class RequestForm {
    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateCreated;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateUpdated;

    // Other hibernate columns...
}
```

When I retrieve the `RequestForm` entity from the database, the format of `dateCreated.toString()` and `dateUpdated.toString()` is unpredictable, sometimes it returns `2018-06-12 18:21:43.818` and sometimes `Tue Jun 12 18:21:43 PHT 2018`

I think it was caused by the `@Temporal` annotation, is there a way to prevent this? Thank you.

EDIT: If it helps, I am using MySQL 5.7

Comment: I am not sure but maybe you should also tell which RDBMS you are using. It might be part of the problem.

Comment: toString() is not designed to build code depens on, only for short displaying for debugging. When need stable format, use other methods

Comment: The first one is displayed when Hibernate read a value from the DB as a java.sql.Timestamp. The second one is displayed when you store a java.util.Date in the date. You shouldn't rely on the toString of the date. Just format it with a date formatter when you want a string in a given format. Also, Java 8 is out for quite some years now. You'd better switch to java.time.Instant.